# Content in nav menu is pushed to the left

Tags: html, css, laravel, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to build my first project using Laravel, using blade and Bootstrap as a HTML/CSS framework.

I am having some difficulties figuring out what is causing an annoying bug. I have several pages that include the nav menu. ONLY on the index page the content of the nav menu is pressed to the left.

I found out what code parts cause this issue but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

This is what happens:
[image]
On the index page the entire content of the navbar is pressed to the left a few pixels.

The full code for the index page is:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
  <h1>New Blog Posts</h1>
  @if(count($posts) > 0)
    @foreach($posts as $post)
      <!-- bouw een entry -->
      <div class="card mb-2">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
              <img class="img-fluid px-2 py-2" style="max-height:250px;" src="/storage/cover_images/{{ $post->cover_image }}">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8 p-1">
              <h3><a href="/posts/{{ $post->id }}">{{ $post->title }}</a></h3>
              {!! substr($post->body, 0, 500).'...   ' !!}<a href="/posts/{{ $post->id }}">Read on</a>
              <small>Written on {{ $post->created_at }} by {{ $post->user->name }}</small>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    @endforeach
    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
        {{ $posts->links() }}
    </div>
  @else
    <p>No posts found.</p>
  @endif
@endsection
```

The 2 lines that both cause the problem are:

```
<img class="img-fluid px-2 py-2" style="max-height:250px;" src="/storage/cover_images/{{ $post->cover_image }}">
```

and

```
{!! substr($post->body, 0, 500).'...   ' !!}<a href="/posts/{{ $post->id }}">Read on</a>
```

Comment: Do you still get the issue if `$posts` is empty? Please can you also add the code for `layouts.app`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I managed to solve the issue and posted the solution. I think I sat behind my screen for too long yesterday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing more people have ran into this during their learning path. Whether or not due to sitting behind their computer for too long.

I overlooked the page length. The length of the index page was larger than the screen height (this did not apply to the other pages), resulting in a scroll-bar appearing.

Adding the scroll-bar, to force it on every page, to the body tag in my CSS solved the issue.

```
body {
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried like this?

```
<a href="{{ url('/posts/' . $post->id) }}">Read on</a>
```

And like this for your image?

```
<img src="{{ asset('storage/cover_images/' . $post->cover_image) }}" />
```

**Please, can you provide the error messages?**